Comparing Linear Mixed Models with and without interaction terms
I would like to compare different models with and without interaction terms to see which one is the best fit for my data. I just wanted to check that my approach is correct.
I construct my models like so
my_model <- lmer(myoutcome ~ predictor1 + predictor2 + 
   predictor3 + covariate1 + (1 | ParticipantID), data = mydata)

my_model2 <- lmer(myoutcome ~ predictor1*predictor2 + 
   predictor1*predictor3 + predictor2*predictor3 + covariate1 +
    (1 | ParticipantID), data = mydata)

my_model3 <- lmer(myoutcome ~ predictor1*predictor2*predictor3 + 
    covariate1 + (1 | ParticipantID), data = mydata)

Then, I would compare them like this and see if adding the two and three-way interaction terms improves the model.
anova(my_model, my_model2, my_model3)

I am also considering factors like parsimony, AICc and log likelihood.
I have the following questions:

Is it correct to include all of the 2-way interaction terms in a single model?
Is it correct to specify both the main effects and interactions in the more complex models? (so predictor1*predictor2 as opposed to predictor1:predictor2
If I am not interested in all the two way interactions, could I compare a model like my_model2.1 <- lmer(myoutcome ~ predictor1*predictor2 + predictor3 + covariate1 + (1 | ParticipantID), data = mydata) also with model3?
Should I also be including my covariates in my interaction models?
When reporting the main effects and interactions, I was taught to report the main effects from the first model, and only the interaction effects from the interaction models. However I am now questioning whether this is correct. For example, with the above approach I get the following model summary with only fixed effects (model_mainef)

                              Est.    2.5%   97.5%   t val.    d.f.      p

(Intercept)                  2.93    2.60    3.25    17.49   99.21   0.00
predictor1                   0.04   -0.25    0.34     0.29   66.86   0.78
predictor2                   1.07    0.65    1.49     4.96   69.07   0.00
predictor3                   0.22    0.04    0.41     2.40   71.43   0.02
covariate1                  -0.23   -0.58    0.12    -1.30   69.20   0.20

And this summary with one 2-way interaction (model_int)

                              Est.    2.5%   97.5%   t val.     d.f.      p

(Intercept)                   2.61    2.27    2.94    15.18   112.75   0.00
predictor1                    0.72    0.35    1.09     3.84    68.01   0.00
predictor2                    1.70    1.22    2.18     6.94   112.40   0.00
predictor3                    0.22    0.04    0.40     2.43    72.87   0.02
covariate1                   -0.24   -0.58    0.10    -1.37    70.89   0.17
predictor1:predictor2        -1.32   -1.83   -0.81    -5.05    66.26   0.00

anova(model_mainef, model_int)

              npar    AIC     BIC     logLik    deviance  Chisq  Df Pr(>Chisq)    
model_mainef    7     406.98  427.37   -196.49   392.98                         
model_int       8     385.94  409.24   -184.97   369.94  23.043  1  1.584e-06 ***


We can see that one of the variables which is non-significant in the model with only fixed effects (second row), is now significant when including the interaction term in the model (it is one of the variables in the interaction). When reporting the results, should I use the values from the first or second table? Note that I am not talking about interpretation - since the interaction qualifies the main effect anyway, I just want to know which data to include in my results table :)
Thanks in advance!
EDIT: I have a 2x2 mixed groups study design with one between-groups variable (2 levels) and one within-groups variable (2 levels), hence why I am using mixed-modelling. I have data which I've collected for confirmatory hypothesis testing (i.e., inferential statistics)

Are you interested in prediction, or inference ? And, what is your research question ?

Inference - I have hypotheses and collected data to test them. My research question is psychological, in this case we manipulated performance of a system (good, bad) and behaviour (consistent, unpredictable) and measured the effect on perceived usability of the system, with some self-reported covariates like self-efficacy. My analyses are a combination of confirmatory and exploratory.

Can you please edit your question to include your results as text rather than in an image/screenshot format?

I added the results in text!

Re Q4: Are you asking whether the covariate should be there at all, or are you asking whether you should also include interactions with the covariate? Can we assume that you have enough observations to comfortably estimate all parameters and their uncertainty even for the most complex model? Is this experimental data with a controlled and planned design?

I'm asking whether I should include interactions with the covariate! I assume yes since I'm comparing more complex models with less complex ones, so I guess everything should be the same except for the addition of the interaction term, but I just wanted to make sure. And yes, I did a simulated power analysis prior to data collection to determine the number of participants needed to detect both interaction and main effects.

In the reply to my comment you say that you are interested in inference and that this study is a "combination of confirmatory and exploratory". I would caution you that using the same data for exploratory work, finding "significant" estimates for the variables and interactions between, and then using the very same data to test hypothesis, is usually a bad idea and runs a serious risk of overfitting.
Which variables to include and which interactions between them to include should be informed by knowledge of the subject area. If you think that the "effect" of a variable (or an interaction between variables) is different depending on the values of another variable, then you should include an interaction between the variable (or interaction) and the other variable.

Is it correct to include all of the 2-way interaction terms in a single model?

It is correct if you have reason to think that, for each interaction, the "effect" of one of the variables differs according to values of the other one.

Is it correct to specify both the main effects and interactions in the more complex models? (so predictor1*predictor2 as opposed to predictor1:predictor2

Yes, it is almost always a good idea to include the main effects as well as the interaction terms.

If I am not interested in all the two way interactions, could I compare a model like my_model2.1 <- lmer(myoutcome ~ predictor1*predictor2 + predictor3 + covariate1 + (1 | ParticipantID), data = mydata) also with model3?

Yes. That model is nested within model 3.

Should I also be including my covariates in my interaction models?

This seems like a repeat of the second question. Yes, if you want to include an interaction, then also include the main effects.

When reporting the main effects and interactions, I was taught to report the main effects from the first model, and only the interaction effects from the interaction models. However I am now questioning whether this is correct.

I have seen that recommendation before. It does not make sense to me to report main effects from one model and interaction effects from another.

Thanks so much!!! To clarify, I am not running exploratory analyses and then confirmatory, I have some confirmatory hypotheses a-priori, which I am testing (i.e., the main effects of predictor 1 and 2) but did not have directional hypotheses about if/how they would interact, so I did not pre-register this (but did include enough participants to test for interactions). So I am first running only models to test my confirmatory hypotheses, and then conducting additional exploratory analyses.

Hey Robert, I am guessing that the person's recommendation to report main effects from one model and interaction effect from another is due to the fact that lower-order coefficients in a model with interaction term are actually conditional effects (effect of X2 when X1=0). Given that interaction model will have conditional effects, how do you recommend reporting main effects in a model with interaction terms?
https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/interpreting-lower-order-coefficients-when-the-model-contains-an-interaction/

@JElder thanks for your comment. In order to be fully transparent I would report the results of 1) the main effects model (with no interactions) and 2) both the main effects and interactions from the interactions model

@RobertLong ah great! We’re in agreement then. Thanks for your thoughts— I agree that reporting both is best approach

I agree with Robert's answer to 1, 2, 3, and 5. Just about exactly what I would have written.
For 4, I think the OP means the variable labeled "covariate" in the table, which is not part of the interactions. Yes, I think you should include it. If a covariate is useful in a main effect model, it ought to be useful in an interaction model. Also, if you include it in the main effect model and not the interaction model, it will make comparison much trickier.
for your last question, can you say where you saw this advice? It makes no sense to me whatsoever. Reporting results from different models as if they were from the same one seems like a serious violation. However, some authors do report BOTH the main effect model and the interaction model. That's OK. Just don't mix them.

Thanks! It was advice given to me by another researcher when I was learning about mixed modelling. But intuitively it does make more sense to report either only the model that best fits the data, or report both models.
